# visit to mother grave

Tags: germany, refugees, pakistan

I have lived in Germany since 2011 and I have had refugee status since 2017. My mother died in 2013. I want to visit her grave. How can I do that? I need only 10 days to go back to my country Pakistan.

Comment: Are you Pakistani and is it Pakistan you are a refugee from?  If so, be very careful, I read that you might lose refugee status if you visit the country you fled from, so you might not be able to visit her grave.